# Reference for Shalika germs of GL(n)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, p-adic-groups

I was reading the two Repka papers where he computes the leading and subleading Shalika germs for $GL_n$ and I was wondering, where are we since then? Have these germs (and the integrals) been computed somewhere? Especially if there is a reference using similar methods or something relatively simple.

The following may be a too general question, but what do we know to date about Shalika germs? What is your viewpoint of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 2015 [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-17987-2_3) (also on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.3891)) by Frechette, Gordon, and Robson can serve as a summary of the status with pointers to the literature:

> Shalika germs first appeared in the papers of Shalika and
>   Harish-Chandra. For a survey of their role in harmonic analysis on
>   $p$-adic groups we refer to the beautiful article by [Kottwitz](http://groups.claymath.org/library/proceedings/cmip04.pdf#page=405) (in particular, sections 6, 17, and 27).
>   Shalika germs, by definition, are functions on the set of regular
>   semisimple elements in a Lie algebra, yet except for those defined on
>   a few Lie algebras of small rank, their exact values elude
>   computation. Here we use a general theorem about uniform bounds for
>   motivic functions to estimate the absolute values of the Shalika germs
>   in a uniform way over all local fields of a given (sufficiently large)
>   residue characteristic.